# How to handle 20M+ records from tables with same structure in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, merge, bigdata

I have to handle 25M rows of data that I have collected and transformed from about 50 different sources. Every source leads to about 500.000 to 600.000 rows. Each record has the same structure, regardless the source (let say: id, title, author, release_date)

For flexibility, I would prefer to create a dedicated table for each source, (then I can clear/drop data from a source and reload/upload data very quickly (using LOAD INFILE)). This way, it seems very easy to truncate the table with no risk to delete rows from other sources.

But then I don't know how to select records having the same author across the different tables, and cherry on the cake, with pagination (LIMIT keyword).

Is the only solution to store everything into a single huge table and deal with the pain of indexing/backuping a 25M+ database or is there a kind of abstract layer to virtually merge 50 tables into a virtual one.

It is probably a usual question for a dba, but I could not find any answer yet...
Any help/idea much appreicated. Thx

Comment: It sounds like you're describing partitioning

Comment: What you're describing is partitioning. I don't know enough about MySQL to know if that's an answer for you though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This might be a good spot for [MySQL partitoning](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/partitioning-overview.html).

This lets you handle a big volume of data, while giving you the opportunity to run DML operations on a specific partition when needed (such as `truncate`, or event `drop`) very efficiently, and without impacting the rest of your data. Partitioning selection is also supported in `LOAD DATA` statements.

You can run queries across partitions as you would with a normal table, or target a specific partition when you need to (which can be done very efficiently).

In your specific use case, [list partitioning](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/partitioning-list.html) seems like a relevant choice: you have a pre-defined list of sources, so you would typically have one partition per source.